# Dell Vostro 1015 Wifi Problem

Tags: wireless

ubuntu joined the family today, on my own computer not connecting to the internet today, wifi setup yaptım.Dell Vostro 1015, builds vessels know how this problem.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to say?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please try and search for yourself a bit. There are a few related problems that can be found with Google. For instance, have a look at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1534272&p=10074920#post10074920.

Answer (score 0):

[this is what is said about your Dell computer; click here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201010-6649/)

Maybe it is usefull to put an internetcable into your computer and go to systemsettings tab hardware icon for additional drivers and let that process run. If an additional driver is available, install it by clicking 'install'.

For WIFI setup look at the upper right corner (a bit to the left of it) for a triangle-icon and click that (without the internetcable connected); see if there is any name from available networks displayed. If so, search for your personal network ; click on that and give in your password for that network. Normally you should have a WIFI-connection.

Succes !

Comment: I need wifi driver, I know where to recei

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to get the ultimate drivers. Go to google (for example) and then write in the search box: mes drivers.
Select the first or second ítem on the list and this will return several issues related to the most current drivers for your laptop or PC. 
Install the Active X control required (automatically) and search for the wifi driver you need.
Install it and try again.

Regards.
Salomon Aguilera.

Answer (score 0):

for those who don't know this, vostros have a physical switch on the left side of the laptop too. it is on the left up close to the monitor hinge. it just slides off and on for wifi. I was having a problem turning wifi on in the software and ran across this switch.